# How to make JTable cells default to overwrite mode

Tags: java, jtable

JTable cells by default are in append mode when the cell is double clicked on.
Is there a way to make the cell default to overwrite mode instead, IOW, select the contents of the cell so that if the user started typing the old text would be replaced by the new text without having to manually erase it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this by creating your own [TableCellEditor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html), which can be assigned to the parent table using [setCellEditor()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setCellEditor%28javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor%29). This object is a factory that is called by the JTable whenever the user starts editing a cell, to create the field used to do the actual editing. You can return your own JTextField, and simply avoid setting the old value to achieve what your asking. You'll also have to attach a listener to the text field to update the value in the table when the user has finished typing.

Comment: Using this approach you may need to create a custom editor for every type of data. One for String, Integer etc.

Answer (score 4):

You might find the [Table Select All Editor](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/table-select-all-editor/) helpful.

Comment: I took a look at RXTable to see if I could understand, but this is hard since I am working with a NetBeans generated swing.JTable(). Also, I am adding and removing rows from the table based on user input. Is there a way to add a listener that will simply do the select all on a single click (or TAB navigation) to the cell, when the cell receives focus? I'd like to get this NetBeans JTable to behave like an Excel table since so many are comfortable with that user interface.

Comment: In case this helps someone else, the key code in RXTable (the editCellAt() method) was very easy to pull out and adapt into another custom table subclass.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented the following method [addDeletePreviousOnEditBehavior] that works fine! Note that you need to use some [TableCellEditor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html). To do so add the following code:

```
JTable table=new JTable();
JTextField field=new JTextField();
addDeletePreviousOnEditBehavior(field);
table.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(field));
```

The method is:

```
public static void addDeletePreviousOnEditBehavior(final JComponent field) {

    field.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
            field.putClientProperty(DELETE_ON_EDIT, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
        }
    });

    field.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
            if ((!(ke.isActionKey()
                    || isSpecial(ke.getKeyCode())))
                    && ((Boolean) field.getClientProperty(DELETE_ON_EDIT))) {
                System.out.println("Key:" + ke.getKeyCode() + "/" + ke.getKeyChar());
                field.putClientProperty(DELETE_ON_EDIT, false);
                if (field instanceof JFormattedTextField) {
                    ((JFormattedTextField) field).setValue(null);
                }
                if (field instanceof JTextComponent) {
                    ((JTextComponent) field).setText(null);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
           // do nothing
        }
    });
}
```